# To prove E[Y] = E[E[Y∣X]] if X is continuous and Y is discrete

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, education

Given Y is discrete, E[Y] = $\sum_{y}^{} y * P(Y=y)$ and given X is continuous, E[X] = $\int_{x}^{} x * P(X=x)$.
Then,
$$E[E[Y|X]] = E[\sum_{y}^{} y * P(Y=y|X)]$$
$$=\int_{x}^{} \sum_{y}^{} y * P(Y=y|X) * f_X(x) dx $$
$$=\sum_{y}^{} y * \int_{x}^{} P(Y=y|X) * f_X(x) dx $$
$$=\sum_{y}^{} y* P(Y=y)$$
$$= E[Y] $$

Is this correct?

Comment: I think so. Also, I think there is a typo in the second last equality: $y$ is missing in the summation.

Comment: You should write $P(Y = y \mid X = x)$ and then think what does this mean considering $X$ is absolutely continuous.